# SKStoreReviewController requestReview not working on iOS 14

Tags: ios, storekit

I've implemented the native review prompt using this code

```objectivec
if (@available(iOS 10.3, *)) {
  [SKStoreReviewController requestReview];
  resolve(@YES);
}
```

But it's not showing in debug on a real iPhone X on iOS 14.4.
I'm seeing this error in the device's log (in the general console not Xcode):

```
No "UIViewServicePermittedViewControllerClasses" array in View Service bundle "com.apple.ios.StoreKitUIService"'s Info.plist. Cannot check validity of request for class "ServiceReviewViewController". This will become failure in a future build.
```

[image]

It's showing perfectly fine on an iPhone 6 on iOS 12.5. (the Submit button is greyed out).

I noticed that `requestReview` is [deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller/2851536-requestreview) since iOS 14 so I tried to use the new method passing a Scene:

```objectivec
if (@available(iOS 14.0, *)) {
  [SKStoreReviewController requestReviewInScene:[UIApplication.sharedApplication.connectedScenes allObjects][0]];
} else if (@available(iOS 10.3, *)) {
  [SKStoreReviewController requestReview];
}
```

With the exact same error in the device's logs.
I made sure that `[UIApplication.sharedApplication.connectedScenes allObjects][0]` was not nil.

Has anyone seen this issue before?

Answer (score 4):

After a couple of days of investigation, we finally found that the review prompt is showing if we remove a modal window we're showing as a splash screen while some resources are loaded.

That seems to be tripping Storekit's logic to show the prompt on the visible window.

**UPDATE**

Seems like the culprit was this particular line:

```swift
window.windowLevel = modalWindow.windowLevel + 1
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer. It helped me as well, the same issue.